# XSD validation always passes

Tags: c#, xml, validation, xsd

I am using following code to validate XML agains the XSD:

```
public static bool IsValidXmlOld(string xmlFilePath, string xsdFilePath)
{
    if (File.Exists(xmlFilePath) && File.Exists(xsdFilePath))
    {
        try
        {
            XDocument xdocXml = XDocument.Load(xmlFilePath);
            var schemas = new XmlSchemaSet();
            schemas.Add(null, xsdFilePath);

            Boolean result = true;
            xdocXml.Validate(schemas, (sender, e) =>
            {
                result = false;
            });

            return result;
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Logging logic + error handling logic
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    throw new Exception("Either the Schema or the XML file does not exist Please check");
}
```

For some reason, it always returns true even if the XML is not valid for given XSD. I picked up this code from following link:

[Validate XML against XSD in a single method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10025986/validate-xml-against-xsd-in-a-single-method). sounds like that result= false never gets called even if the xml is completely invalid.

I have a pair of valid and invalid XML that goes against a particular XSD

1. [Valid XML](http://www.codeshare.io/yMRa2)
2. [XSD](http://www.codeshare.io/Qawjp)
3. [Invalid XML](http://www.codeshare.io/QbFaw)

If I try to validate them on [This](http://www.utilities-online.info/xsdvalidation/#.VVuigPlVhBc) web site then the valid one passes the validation test against the invalid one BUT the invalid XML **Fails** the test. However, the code above passes both the XMLs invariably.

At the same time it fails the validation  when I use some basic XML like following:

```
 XDocument doc2 = new XDocument(
                        new XElement("Root",
                            new XElement("Child1", "content1"),
                            new XElement("Child3", "content1")
                        )
                    );
```

with following error:

```
The 'Root' element is not declared.: {0}
```

Now, it clearly demonstrates that the code is **not completely incapable of failing a validation**. However, what is so special about the 3. [Invalid XML](http://www.codeshare.io/QbFaw) that the code passes that particular XML when [This Site](http://www.utilities-online.info/xsdvalidation/#.VVuigPlVhBc) clearly fails it?

Comment: Maybe you need to enable warnings: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30263114/xmlreader-always-validates-a-xsd-file-against-another-xsd-file-as-valid

Comment: @CoffeeBean I think you meant to respond to @dbc?

Comment: @dbc: that is before .NET 3.5. I used the new method but that also does not seem to work